# Install manually Crypto swift library. Unexpected platform condition

Tags: ios, swift, installation, cryptoswift

I am trying to install Crypto swift library for AES encryption manually based on their instructions. but I get two compile error. First one is :
Unexpected platform condition (expected 'os', 'arch', or 'swift')
and the second one is: No such module 'Glibc'
I do not want to install it with cocoa pods. 
The library link is:
https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

Comment: I sounds like you have chosen the wrong library. Are you sure the one you've chosen is compatible with iOS? Can you post a link to the lib?

Comment: I added the link of library: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

Comment: @Chris Yes it is a famous library. I can do it with Cocoapods and it works, but i need to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurred because I had Swift 4 but by this command,(git submodule add https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift.git) the latest code (swift 4.1) added to my project. The solution is adding the branch which is for Swift4.

```
Swift versions support

Swift 1.2: branch swift12 version <= 0.0.13
Swift 2.1: branch swift21 version <= 0.2.3
Swift 2.2, 2.3: branch swift2 version <= 0.5.2
Swift 3.1, branch swift3 version <= 0.6.9
Swift 3.2, branch swift32 version = 0.7.0
Swift 4.0, branch swift4 version >= 0.7.1
Swift 4.1, branch master version >= 0.9.0
```